# Can i use NGINX to deliver static confidential (verification documents like driving licence) images?

Tags: java, nginx, spring-boot

I am just starting to learn about NGINX. But i have some doubt whether NGINX will serve as per my requirement.

Problem:
In my web app ,i am uploading user's documents at server file system lets say in /opt/myproject/images directory.

I need a way  to serve documents (confidential like Driving licence) of user using NGINX but i also need a way to check whether that user is authorized to fetch this resource.

This is my requirement. Can NGINX fill my requirements ?

Note : My app server is tomcat (in build in spring boot and my app is running as jar file)

Or is there any better way?

Note: I dont want much load on my app server thats why i am using NGINX

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do that. What you need to do is use `X-Accel` headers. So you will define a block in your nginx config

```
location /confidential_images {
   root /opt/myproject/images;
   internal;
}
```

Marking the API internal means only nginx can make the call to this block. Now your code will have the information about what images the user should see. So you will create a endpoint in code which the user can reach, where you can check which images they can reach. And then you can return `X-Accel-Redirect` header from your code

in your code you will return below header

```
X-AccelRedirect: /confidential_images/<path inside images folder>;
```

Nginx will then redirect it internal to the internal location we define and that image will be server. The key is not to let nginx serve images directly, but to use internal locations which are controlled using the application code.

Read more on https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/x-accel/

Comment: hey thanx for the comment i am looking into it,

Comment: I have one question. Can in have some filter like mechanism? It will help in checking weather incoming request has authorization token present by executing some script php/servelt before serving static images.

Comment: Yes, as i mentioned the request will always go to you code first and then you redirect it to internal nginx url to serve the file. So you can use tokens, cookies, anything you like